# X- header missing out on reply

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I am trying to organize emails in my app. For this purpose I add tried adding a custom header to my outgoing emails. Something like this

```
X-Discussion-Id: 400
```

The problem is that, I don't receive this on reply. Is there any solution to this?? I have tried the method where we add +number to the reply-to and from. the problem with that approach is that it creates many new contacts for the users and I don't like that.